# I am setting up ambari-server , but it says I need to setup MySQL drive?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, ambari

> Before starting Ambari Server, you must copy the MySQL JDBC driver JAR file to /usr/share/java and set property "server.jdbc.driver.path=[path/to/custom_jdbc_driver]" in ambari.properties.

Comment: Download mysql java connector and setup Ambari with it. Error will be resolved

Comment: Yeah, this seems self-explanatory... Have you tried searching elsewhere for where to get the MySQL JDBC Driver?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.tar.gz) to download mysql jdbc driver jar. Once it is downloaded, extract it, then rename it as mysql-connector-java.jar and move it to the path /usr/share/java

Then execute the command given below to ensure the database connectivity,

**ambari-server setup --jdbc-db=mysql --jdbc-driver=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar**